# two ways to call the declared function with parameters in string

Tags: javascript

I have a declaration of a function where each parameter is a string and I am trying to trigger the below method in at least 2 ways to call the function. I am new to Javascript and also went through few documentation to understand the logic but unable to figure out. If someone can please help me in this. Below is my declared function and I want to know how can I do it.

```
function displayValue(param1, param2, param3){

}
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with this function? can you please elaborate?

Comment: i have been given this question as an assignment with the above mentioned requirement where I need to call a function in at least two ways.

Comment: `displayValue('1','2','3')` and `displayValue("One","Two","Three")`

Comment: `displayValue('one', 'two', 'three')` and `displayValue('four', 'five')` are two ways you can call this function. For the second call with 'four' & 'five' the value of param3 will be `undefined`. You can also call it as `displayValue(1, 'two', 3)` ... a mix of integer and string parameters.

Comment: If you're having difficulty with an assignment, it's best to go to the instructor or TA so they're aware of where you are at with the material, and can provide background, additional explanations, and support for the class material. They are there to help you succeed. Note that asking about [homework](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/90527) on SO has extra considerations, and special guidelines.

Comment: thank you all for responding and making me understand the logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Directly calling function providing strings as params

```
displayValue('hi', 'there', 'sir');
```

2. Using variables as params and passing them into the function

```
const firstString = 'hi';
const secondString = 'there';
const thirdString = 'sir';
displayValue(firstString, secondString, thirdString);
```

Comment: thank you `tuckermassad` for making me understand the logic as it really helped me.